# Trying to delete an XML file throws "The process cannot access the file..." error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, delete-file

I have a little app that is supposed to read through an XML document that the user uploads. If the file doesn't have the proper nodes, the file is deleted and the user is notified.

However, the file is always locked when I try to delete it, both in code and through windows explorer. It stays locked until I refresh the page in IE.

```
myDoc.Load(FileUpload2.FileContent);
string XMLpath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PDFLocation"]) + FileUpload2.FileName;
myDoc.Save(XMLpath);
file = new FileInfo(XMLpath);

//here I check if the file is valid. If not, delete

file.Delete(); //This is where it throws the "cannot access the file" error
```

the full text of the error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\project\files\file.xml' because it is being used by another process.
```

I tried putting in `FileUpload2.FileContent.Dispose();` and `FileUpload2.Dispose();` before the delete statement, but no luck.

How do I release the file for deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't save the XML file to disk at all until you know it's valid.

To answer your question, you left an open `FileStream` somewhere in the elided code.
You need to `Dispose()` it, preferably by using a `using` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the file after saving it. You cannot delete the file if your application has it open.

Comment: Ok, awesome. How do I do that?

Comment: @Jimmy - its hard to tell by your code, but if your opening the XML file using [Create Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create.aspx), then just use the [Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.close.aspx). If you are just passing a string into XMLDocument.Load method, then don't. Instead, open the file yourself using an IOStream and pass the stream to the XMLDocument.Load function. Do you need an example?

Comment: The problem was that the code that checks the file isn't my own. I just assumed that it was my fault this wasn't working. Turns out, the problem was in that code. There was a filestream left open. I patched it up and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what type of myDoc is... but if it has a method "`Close`" or "`Dispose`" then call that before trying to delete...

EDIT:
if it does not have such a method then `myDoc = null;` could help.

Answer (score 0):

After saving yout file you neeed to close it as well as flush the memory.